# emacs 25: display-buffer-other-window behavior change, how to tune for the old way?

Tags: buffers, files

I have a number of macros for browsing source code for many emacs versions.  I wrote this in 2009 and it's been solid until upgrading to U18.04.  I know it worked in U16.04:

> ```
> (defun get-file-from-buffer-other-window ()
>   "Load a file into another window referenced by the string on the current line"
>   (interactive)
>
>   ;; get the filename and lineno
>   (setq vals (get-fileline))
>   (print vals)
>
>   ;; load the filename into the next window and goto linenumber
>   (switch-to-buffer-other-window (find-file-noselect (nth 0 vals)))
>   (goto-line (nth 1 vals))
> )
> ```

I split a frame and have a file list in one window, select a file from the list, which loads it into a buffer and loads the buffer in the other window.  Two windows in the frame.

In the new version 25.2.2, the default behavior changed.  Now selecting a file opens a NEW window in the frame. Look at five files (key bind to f8) and five new windows are created. I traced the issue to the windows.el display-buffer macro. There is a tuning action named *display-buffer-base-action*. I try changing the behavior, specifically to *display-buffer-reuse-window* but cannot get it to recreate the behavior emacs has defaulted since I wrote it in 2009.  WTF?

Any ideas?  I'm sure it is something to do with display-buffer-reuse-window and this documentation.
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Precedence-of-Action-Functions.html

Dave

Comment: Incidentally, the primary macro to load the file/buffer into the existing window works fine using *switch-to-buffer*.  But then I lose the source file list.  I have additional macros that search the source file list for regex patterns and then I can click on the file/lines that match the pattern.  Much more helpful to search a large code base than tags.

Comment: I'm testing with the following macros in a frame with two windows.  *foo* should be loaded in a new window in the frame and *bar* should be loaded into the same window - at least that's the way it used to work....
<br \>
(switch-to-buffer-other-window (get-buffer-create "*foo*"))
(switch-to-buffer-other-window (get-buffer-create "*bar*"))

Answer (score 1):

As with all my emacs work, I take it for granted until something doesn't work and then I need to dig into it.  It's a tool but you need to sharpen it to cut bait...

Not the best solution but here's what works for me.  I took it from:

[How to force completions buffer to appear in a side window?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21416/how-to-force-completions-buffer-to-appear-in-a-side-window)

```
(defun display-on-side (buffer &optional not-this-window frame)
  (let* ((window (or (minibuffer-selected-window)
                     (selected-window)))
         (display-buffer-function nil)
         (pop-up-windows nil))
    (with-selected-window (or window (error "display-on-side"))
      (when (one-window-p t)
        (split-window-horizontally))
      (display-buffer buffer not-this-window frame))))

(setq display-buffer-function 'display-on-side)

;; unit test, should open in the same side window.
(display-buffer (get-buffer-create "*foo*"))
(display-buffer (get-buffer-create "*bar*"))
```